# How do I write the output of Portage to a txt file?

Tags: shell-script, tty, cat, output

I would like to be able to write the output of Portage commands, along with other commands, that I perform in tty (that is, the screen-wide terminals started with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd> where n represents an integer between 1 and 6. These terminals are started using the `getty` command, to my knowledge) where there is no clipboard, to a text file. Now I read on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1379903) that maybe the Unix command `cat` might be able to do this, if properly used. Unfortunately, following the command suggested there does not seem to add the complete output of the `emerge` command to a text file. See I ran:

```
emerge dev-qt/qtwayland > cat >> /home/fusion809/output.txt
```

where fusion809 is my username, and it only wrote four lines of output to output.txt, namely:

```
Calculating dependencies  ....... .. ....... done!
[ebuild   R    ] media-libs/mesa-11.0.4  USE="-wayland*" ABI_X86="32*"
[ebuild   R    ] dev-qt/qtgui-5.5.1  USE="-egl* -evdev* -ibus*"
[ebuild   R    ] dev-qt/qtwayland-5.5.1  USE="-egl*"
```

I also tried:

```
emerge dev-qt/qtwayland > /home/fusion809/output.txt
```

and:

```
emerge dev-qt/qtwayland >> /home/fusion809/output.txt
```

both of which wrote the same output to output.txt.

Comment: What else are you expecting in the output?

Comment: Well everything else that appears in the terminal... like when it downloads the source code packages, compiles and then installs them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.  In Unix/Linux there's also an error stream.  Every command gets standard input, standard output, and standard error.

You've been working with standard output.  To also capture the standard error stream from the command use `2>`.  For example:

```
emerge dev-qt/qtwayland > emerge.out 2> emerge.err
```

Now if you want the standard output *and* error to go into the *same* file, use `2>&1` to tell the shell to send the standard error output to the same place as the standard output:

```
emerge dev-qt/qtwayland > emerge.out 2>&1
```

Also, if you need to reference and learn more, you can always look this up in the shell man page `man sh`.

Thanks for the informative and well-thought question!

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need the `> cat` there.  in fact, that just creates another file called `cat` in the current dir.  and if you meant to type `| cat`, that's superfluous, you can redirect the output without piping it through cat.
2. `emerge dev-qt/qtwayland > /home/fusion809/output.txt` will save **ALL** of the stdout output from your `emerge` command to `/home/fusion809/output.txt`.  ALL of it.  if there's only 4 lines in the file, that's because `emerge` only printed 4 lines to stdout.
3. emerge may have printed more stuff to `stderr`.  if you want to capture that too, try `emerge dev-qt/qtwayland >& /home/fusion809/output.txt`.  That redirects both stdout and stderr to the same file.
4. the difference between `>` and `>>` is that `>` erases the file if it exists before creating it, and `>>` appends to the file if it already exists or creates it if it doesn't (depending on shell options).
5. if you want to capture the output to a file **AND** see it on screen at the same time, use `tee`.  For example:

`emerge dev-qt/qtwayland |& tee -a /home/fusion809/output.txt`

`tee`'s `-a` option tells it to append rather than erase and overwrite.